# How to show multiple ListView in a single content page with items of different data types in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When putting multiple ListView in a single StackLayout it's displaying the lists with multiple scrollings. I want to display multiple ListView with different data types in a single scrolling.

Comment: do you have a picture of what youre trying to do?

Comment: One possible hack, if you'd like, is to actually set the ListView's header to be one collection and its actual content to be that of the other. Also keep in mind a list view by default comes with scrolling. So a ListView within a scrollview is not going to be the best user experience. If your collection of items isn't going to be too big say <20 or 30 you can do a stack layout with an item template and wrap that in a scroll view

Comment: The reason I caution the stack layout with too many items is that it can quite quickly become unresponsive

Comment: Can you provide more details of exactly what you want to achieve? You can have a single ListView with items of different data types.

Comment: To achieve your requirement. List may need to load completely. That will go against [listview's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#caching-strategy) actual usage. Its good try as  @MateusHenrique comment. OR You can try using [layout binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts#:~:text=Bindable%20layouts%20enable%20any%20layout,each%20item%20with%20a%20DataTemplate%20.).

Comment: I want to add multiple ListView with different data types in a single content page It's displaying the ListViews but with different scroll bars. If I added 3 ListView in a single content page it divides the screen into 3 parts with 3 scroll bars. I want 3 listviews with 1 scroll bar.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to put both ListViews in a ScrollView and disabling their scroll bars?

```
  <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
      <ListView x:Name="lv1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"/>
      <ListView x:Name="lv2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" />
    </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
```

But you may still have scrolling problems, as the ScrollView documentation explicitly states that

> ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition, ScrollView
> objects should not be nested with other controls that provide
> scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView.

Which functionalities of the ListView you want to be working independently for those ListViews? Scrolling? Selection?